# How to Configure 2 IP Address on Same Network Interface to Allow Specific Ports to be Accessed by Specific IP?

Tags: networking, firewalld, debian-stretch

I have 2 IP addresses on the same network interface: 192.168.1.100 & 192.168.1.101. I want to be able to access SSH via 192.168.1.100 and HTTP via 192.168.1.101. I'm using Debian 9.8 and firewalld to control the firewall.

Below are current zone configurations.

**Zone: Public**

```
root@server ~ # firewall-cmd --list-all --zone=public
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources: 192.168.1.100
  services: ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

**Zone: Special**

```
root@server ~ # firewall-cmd --list-all --zone=special
special(active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources: 192.168.1.101
  services: http
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

**Reloading Firewall**

```
root@server ~ # firewall-cmd --reload
```

For some reason, I'm able to access SSH via 92.168.1.100 & 192.168.1.101 and I'm unable to access HTTP from neither 192.168.1.100 nor 192.168.1.101.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the `firewalld` option format. But to me it looks that the rules are allowing connections from the server's IP address `192.168.1.100` to SSH, and from server's IP address `192.168.1.101` to HTTP.

You should use the `destination` address, if you really want to use the firewall way to achieve this.

However, the best approach here is to bind the services to different ports.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be able to access SSH via 192.168.1.100 and HTTP via 192.168.1.101.

You can also just simply have the SSH server bind to 192.168.1.100, [likely via the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sshd_config.5.html), setting `ListenAddress 192.168.1.100`

You can have HTTP server bind to just 192.168.1.101, likely in the configuration file named something like `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`, assuming an Apache HTTP server, where you can set `Listen 192.168.1.101:80` in place of `Listen 80`.

That might have some uwanted side effects, such as preventing you from accessing the server via `localhost`/`127.0.0.1` via something like `http://localhost/path/to...`.

Comment: Thank you but I was wondering why my setup wasn't working. Can you please help with that?